# HttpCookie with Expires set returns DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm seeing something of an oddity when setting a cookie...

Action:

```
string cookieName = "foo";
string cookieValue = "bar";

//Set a cookie in the response, along with the Expires.
this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(
  new HttpCookie(cookieName, cookieValue)
  {
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
  }
);
```

When debugging, I can see that this new cookie has an expiry of one hour in the future, and yet, when I look at the cookie in the view, the expiry isn't there...

View:

```
<%= Request.Cookies.Get("foo").Value %>
```

Returns `bar`.

```
<%= Request.Cookies.Get("foo").Expires %>
```

Returns `01/01/0001 00:00:00`

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking at the *request* - which doesn't contain an expiry time. The server tells the client when the cookie should expire; there's no need for the client to tell the server as well :)

Comment: There is nothing in the Response.Cookies.

Comment: It's not very clear what's going on. You're setting the cookies - are you then examining them in the next request? I wouldn't expect anything in Response.Cookies unless you're adding them.

Comment: My action is basically a SetEnvironmentMode action. In this action, the cookie is set, and returns a RedirectToAction to GetEnvironmentMode.

Comment: I see my problem here, and I understand what you're saying. What I was trying to do was to have a expiry time (which works), but also, in my GetEnvironmentMode view, show the user how much longer was left before that cookie expires.

Comment: I think you'll have to include something in the cookie value to remember that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

`Response.Cookies` is a very different thing from `Request.Cookies`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: **First**, if you are looking at the Request before the Response has been pushed to the client, then the Request will not have your updates.

**Second**, if you are setting a cookie and then using a Response.Redirect, your cookie values might not have been pushed to the client. Under the covers Response.Redirect calls "Thread.Abort()", which is kills the thread.

Comment: Well, it's MVC, and I'm doing a RedirectToAction.

Comment: @DanAtkinson have you fixed your issue? i have similar situation. can you help me?

Comment: @DanAtkinson I seen it.. My concern is to manage the remember me. if auth cookie not worked to that expired time then how to manage it? pls share me your thoughts.

Comment: @AbhishekB. Use the Response object. If that's not your answer then I'd suggest you ask a new question rather than tag it onto a comment to something I asked 8 years ago. :)

Comment: @DanAtkinson right. I asked. waiting for the answer and resolutions... Thank you