# How to maintain FormsAuthentication Cookie it's not deleting in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I have getting issue with delete FormsAuthentication ticket cookie with remember me option.. it always showing expired date 01/01/0001, I am setting FormsAuthentication ticket with expired time at the time of login controller.

When the application URL open that time again check the expired time & Auth Cookie. 
everytime it Authentication cookies expired time showing the same..

How to manage FormsAuth ticket with remember me option?

I have search a lots in different forums but not get the exact solutions..

Below screenshot when i have not selected Remember me. 
When I selected remember me it showing time in Expire age. but not handling with C# code.
[image]

```
// Here u is view model object that set the username,password and remember me options.
```

// LOGIN FUNCTION CODE

```
if (u.RememberMe)
{
    int timeout = u.RememberMe ? 525600 : (int)sessionSection.Timeout.TotalMinutes; // Timeout in minutes, 525600 = 365 days.
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, u.Email, DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeout), u.RememberMe, logmodel.UserType);
    string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
    cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
    //cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeout);// Not my line
    //if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    //    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    /// cookie.HttpOnly = true; // cookie not available in javascript.
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
else
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.Email, false);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code used?  Are you manually creating the FormsAuthenticationTIcket?

Comment: Have you checked this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676901/httpcookie-with-expires-set-returns-datetime-minvalue

Comment: @brainMains Yes. creating manually after login check with database.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira I have checked it.. but how to maintain remember me.. Auth cookie never set expire date. how to manage the user is remembered or not..

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.Email, u.RememberMe);`? You can set the timeout to 525600 in the web.config if you really want the cookie to last a year.

Comment: @TiesonT. i am using same. if remember me then store for long time. otherwise as per form timeout.. but when user logout with persist cookie then cookie not deleting. that's the issue.

Comment: i have used formauthentication.logout method but cookie still present in browser.. why it not removing.. i cleared response.cookies.clear event cookie not removing from browser..

Comment: It's not entirely obvious what you're actually doing - you don't have a complete example here. One obvious question is, are you redirecting after log out? Expiring a cookie in the browser requires replacing the existing cookie with another cookie that has an expiration date in the past. That will cause the browser to remove the cookie, but it doesn't "go away" until the next page load. That's one of the reasons for the Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Comment: yes. page is redirecting to login view in mvc app, but cookie value still remain. i am setting the past year on expiration..

Comment: Do you have forms authentication enabled on web.config ?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira yes it enabled